# Add custom font family in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I would like add custom font family on my React Native App on iOS. I've no problem with Android, but i've an error in iOS :

> Unrecognized font family 'dinproRegular'

I've use [this link](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e) for setup my font, but no result.

File name : dinproRegular.ttf

Call in react-native : `fontFamily: "dinproRegular" // Test with "Dinpro Regular" too`

No result :(

Anyone have idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Just check the fonts that are currenly installed in Ios or Android:

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-fonts

If you want to add custom fonts:

https://medium.com/@danielskripnik/how-to-add-and-remove-custom-fonts-in-react-native-b2830084b0e4

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've try with Google Font, and it work. Do you think it's because DinPro is not free ? Maybe the file is the problem ?

Comment: I don't think that this could be the error if is the correct file. Did you link your fonts path correctly in the package.json?

Comment: Yes :) My path is correct, i've try with other font and it work

Comment: Okey so sure it is a problem with this font type. Maybe you didn't download it well or be sure ios is fully compatible with that font.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you can see what font name you should use in code to let it work
Use below code in AppDelegate.m to get all font names supported in your app.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
      NSLog(@" %@", name);
    }
  }
```